# Google Analytics Hit not sent

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a GA pageview tag firing through GTM with an all pages trigger.  GTM is confirmed on page and actively working, and the tag is firing on all pages and hits are being sent to GA.

All except one page, where the GTM tag fires, but not GA hit is being sent.

Debugging within console, filtering for collect hits.

I've never seen a case where the GTM preview is showing the tag firing, but the browser network hits are not being sent.

Stranger still the other tags, i.e Facebook also in GTM, are being sent.

I'd like to know some points I can take to the web devs to help them debug this as it doesn't appear to be an issue with GTM or the tag.

Any ideas appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Any console error messages when the page loads? Is this page differently served than the other pages? Can you manually send a hit through the console?

Comment: Hi, thanks, no console errors, I'm checking on how the page is served.  Not sure how I'd do the hit manually?

Comment: Try this, see if you get more debug: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en. I've seen this happened when the hit values (eg event values) are invalid and GA just ignores the hit (I'm assuming those checks in the tracker to not send junk to their servers)

Comment: Otherwise you also have this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/debugging

Comment: Thanks Max, looks like the pageview beacon isnt being generated/sent.

Comment: Alright, can you manually copy/paste an event in your browser console (`ga('send', 'event', 'test', 'test', 'test');`) and see what happens.

Comment: Nothing happens, just sits there, this is the page if it helps

Comment: https://cars.suzuki.co.uk/new-cars/offers-finance/0-apr-no-deposit/

Comment: analytics_debug.js:10 Executing Google Analytics commands.
analytics_debug.js:10 Running command: ga("send", "event", "test", "test", "test")
analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Unknown target: undefined
undefined

Comment: I've tried adding the raw global tag code into GTM as a custom tag, and it's worked!  really bizarre.

Comment: "Unkown target" means you are using a named tracker, but forgot to include the tracker call in the name. In your case it happened because GTM automatically names trackers, but your test event did not include the name, so that test told you very little about the actual problem.